# Can I use LetsEncrypt to issue a certificate for a sub-domain that I don't own?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

Trying to figure out impersonation. As I believe a certificate has been issued with Let's Encrypt Authority X3 for a sub-domain to a domain that I know who is the owner to, and they did not issue this certificate.
Is it possible to use Lets Encrypt to issue such certificate to a sub-domain without actually owning it?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances it shouldn't be possible to obtain a Let's Encrypt certificate for a domain you don't control.

To get a new certificate for a domain, the agent requesting the certificate must prove that it controls that domain, typically either through provisioning either a DNS record or an HTTP resource. Once it has done this, it gets an authorized key pair which it can use to request, renew, or revoke certificates.

However:

1. If you lose control of that authorized key pair, anyone with the private key can use it to request certificates for the authorized domain.
2. Ownership and control don't necessarily go together. Company A could own and ultimately control domain.com, but delegate control of subdomain.domain.com to another party if it so wishes. If so, that party could, by design, obtain a certificate for that subdomain without Company A's knowledge or consent.
3. Because of point (2), you may not actually own a domain you think you own. If a web hosting company owns domain.com, and you buy sub.domain.com from them, it's possible they could sell sub.sub.domain.com to someone else, and that someone else may therefore be able to get a certificate for it. See [this question over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/427262/phishing-site-uses-subdomain-that-i-never-registered?noredirect=1&lq=1) for an example of exactly that happening.

Comment: Would name server DOMAINCONTROL.COM allow point (3)? As to let someone own a sub domain of an existing domain.

Comment: @JohnPedro: It depends how it's set up, you'd need to look at the specific DNS records. However, domaincontrol.com is for GoDaddy.com, and they've had well-known problems with spammers engaging in domain-shadowing, using stolen domain registrant credentials to create a bunch of fake and quickly-rotating subdomains, so it may be connected with that. [Here's one story about it](https://threatpost.com/godaddy-shutters-subdomains-snake-oil/144147/).

Comment: Could you point me on what to look at the specific record (if it does indeed allows it) or to an article about it?

Comment: any place to look for to verify how it is set up?